# Python class inheritance: dynamic attribute creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly, but I know you all are smart enough to figure it out :).  I am having trouble condensing some repetitive code in a few python classes. Here is an example of what I mean...

```
class Parent:

    PATH_PROPERTIES = [ 'parent' ]

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.props = { 'parent': path }

    def getPath(self):
        return self.props['parent']


class Child(Parent):

    PATH_PROPERTIES = [ 'child' ]

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.props = { 'child': path }

    def getPath(self):
        return self.props['child']
```

Above, is the current situation, but I would like to reduce some of the duplication by doing something like...

```
class Parent:
    name = 'parent'

    PATH_PROPERTIES = [ name ]

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.props = ( name: path)

    def getPath(self):
        return self.props[name]
```

The last bit of code obviously doesn't work. I can't find anything on Python being able to do C++-like macros.  What is the best way to condense this code?

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you not using standard class attributes (e.g. `Child.path`?)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to store the identifiers `'parent'` and `'child'` as dictionary keys? Some more context would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use inheritance:

```
class Parent:

    PATH_PROPERTIES = [ 'parent' ]

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.props = { self.PATH_PROPERTIES[0]: path }

    def getPath(self):
        return self.props[self.PATH_PROPERTIES[0]]


class Child(Parent):

    PATH_PROPERTIES = [ 'child' ]    


c = Child('path')
print(c.getPath())
```

prints

```
path
```

---

Note that in Python it is usually preferable to use a [property](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) instead of a `getter` function:

```
class Parent:

    PATH_PROPERTIES = 'parent'

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.props = { self.PATH_PROPERTIES: path }

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.props[self.PATH_PROPERTIES]


class Child(Parent):

    PATH_PROPERTIES = 'child'         

c = Child('path')
print(c.path)
```

also prints

```
path
```

Note that `c.path` looks like an attribute lookup, but since `path` is a property, it *calls* the function decorated with `@property`.
The syntax looks nicer than `c.getPath()` and yet gives you the same functionality. There is [a decorator to make setters too](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties).

Comment: Note that you don't need to include an `__init__` method in `Child` if all it's going to do is call the parent class constructor with the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally be able to do this with standard inheritance with a little redesign (as in unutbu's answer), but you could write a factory function to create your classes. This is probably the closest to what you'd do in C++ with macros:

```
def make_class(name, base=object):

    class Class(base):

        PATH_PROPERTIES = [name]

        def __init__(self, path):
            self.props = {name: path}

        @property
        def path(self):
            return self.props[name]

    Class.__name__ = name.title()
    return Class

Parent = make_class("parent")
Child  = make_class("child", Parent)
```